# iOS 8 ABPeoplePickerNavigationController subview - replace cancel button

Tags: objective-c, ios8, abpeoplepickerview, cancel-button

I need to show the address book in my app.

Is it possible to replace or hide the cancel button? Cancel makes no sense in my view (not modal).

```
picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
picker.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
[self.view addSubview:picker.view];
```

`[picker setAllowsCancel:NO]` does exactly what I want, but it's not a public API call.

It's also not possible to hide the navigation bar in iOS 8 anymore.
In iOS 7 I simply wrote:

```
picker.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```